# WMI Configuration Error on SQL 2005 install

Tags: sql-server, windows, installation

SQL Server 2005 is giving me the following error during the "System Check" portion of the initial install: "The SQL Server Configuration Checker cannot be executed due to WMI configuration on the machine  Error:2147749907 (0x80041013)."

Machine is a Dell D620 running XP SP2.

I found a batch command online that is supposed to fix the problem, but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manju Madhavan on my team finally found the answer:

```
rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection WBEM 132 %windir%\inf\wbemoc.inf
```

The setup asked for long list of files that I had to search around to find.  Some were in the i386 folder on the XP SP3 disk, some in %windir%/system32.   As the installer would stop and ask for a file I would search around until I found a copy.

Manju found the answer online and documents it on her [blog](http://manjumadhavan.blogspot.com/2009/04/wmi-failed-to-connect.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Microsoft Operations Manager on your server?

May I suggest disabling any services that utilise the WMI interface, so any performance monitoring software you are using, just whilst you install SQL Server.

Cheers, John

Answer (score 0):

1. Run
2. type or copy paste `rundll32.exe setupapi,InstallHinfSection WBEM 132 %windir%\inf\wbemoc.inf`
3. Connect your Windows XP SP3 CD
4. Find out "i386" folder and click enter and it will copy some file from there and will ask for a `.mof` file.
5. Search for the `.mof` file in where you installed Windows
6. Copy the location of that file and click OK.

Start installing the SQL Server 2005 and I'm sure you will face no more problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what script did you find, but the one I ran worked like a
>   charm. I'm putting here this answer for the ones that got to this post
>   looking for that error message like I did.

Just execute [this](http://www.pinaldave.com/bimg/WMIFIX.zip) *.bat* file.

**Source:** [Pinal Dave's SQL Authority Blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/12/sql-server-fix-error-the-sql-server-system-configuration-checker-cannot-be-executed-due-to-wmi-configuration-on-the-machine-error2147749896-0%C3%9780041008/)